# What's the term for this illustration style common in MMOs/RPGs?

Tags: terminology, art, graphics-design

Often I was asked for the "style", but I am not sure how to describe it. I just say "mix of anime and realism". But what is it actually called, a style like [this example](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/314477986477163085/):

[image: Illustration of a fantasy character]

It's popular and you see it in most of all mmo/rpgs. I know that it's called "stylized" in 3D-Texturing. But how would you call that typical style like in the link above (not meaning the clothes or what it expresses do be, its about the illustration and character style. Like anime, Fortnite (as it has very unique style) and so on)

Comment: I'm not sure if Game Development would be the best Stack Exchange to answer this question. Maybe trying a SE that is more focused on design would be better?

Comment: The link you cite categorizes this example as "Semi/Realistic Anime Art" - are you unsatisfied with that term?

Comment: As TomTsagk says, an artist-focused site like the [Polycount Forum](https://polycount.com/forum) may have better answers for you here.